# IJCADで円を作図するコマンドでビルドエラーになる

Tags: c#, ijcad

IJCAD2017(64bit Pro)で、中心の位置を指定してから半径の値を入力すると、円が作図されるコマンドを作成しています。
半径の指定で終了位置をリアルタイム表示させたいのですが、以下のコード★の箇所でビルドエラーとなってしまいます。
どこを修正すれば良いかわからなくなってしまったので、どなたか教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
//中心座標を入力する
PromptPointOptions pOption = new PromptPointOptions("\n中心座標を入力してください。");
PromptPointResult pResult = editer.GetPoint(pOption);

if (pResult.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
{
    return;
}
Point3d center = pResult.Value;

//半径を入力
PromptDoubleOptions dOption = new PromptDoubleOptions("\n半径を入力してください。");

//開始座標を起点として、終了座標をリアルタイムで表示させる
dOption.UseDefaultValue = true;
dOption.DefaultValue = pResult.Value;　//★

PromptDoubleResult dResult = editer.GetDouble(dOption);
double radius = dResult.Value;
```

＜エラーメッセージ＞
型 'GrxCAD.Geometry.Point3d' を型 'double' に暗黙的に変換できません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

半径を指定するときのDefaultValueについて
PromptDoubleOptionsクラスのDefaultValueは、double型です。
dOption.DefaultValue = pResult.Value とすると、左辺は double、右辺は Point3d となり、型が合わないので、エラーが出ると思われます。
終了座標をリアルタイムで表示させるには、
PromptDouble... を PromptPoint... にして、点の位置を指示させるようにする必要があります。